# Converting String as a Bitmap in android

Tags: android, string, bitmap, bluetooth

I am working on an application which transfers the image from one device to another
device via bluetooth. Now my problem is, I am transfering the bitmap value as byte[] through bluetooth.
Now how to resolve it again into bitmap...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray() method.

```
byte[] byteArray; // the data
int offset = 0; // offset into array
int length = 1024; // length of array
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, offset, length);
```

I think for This string should be Base64 Format. Have a look on [this Link for More Info](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/03/how-to-convert-string-to-bitmap-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

using the [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) you can convert the image