# How to store and retrieve bitmap in sharedPreferences in Android?

Tags: android, imageview

I am new in Android. I want to store my bitmap in sharedPreferences. Can anyone tell me how it will possible? Actually my requirements is, I fetch the image from gallery as well as take picture from camera and I set that Bitmap in my ImageView. These all things work properly. But when I click on back button all ImageView will be empty.

So I want to store that Bitmaps throughout my application.

Can anyone help me? I am very much stuck on this.

Thanks.

Comment: You can go through it.This will definitely help you.

[click here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268519/how-to-store-bitmap-object-in-sharedpreferences-in-android

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hey friends I got the solution of my problem here I post my code so that others can use this solution..

1). on button click -  open camera for captureing image

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);  
mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);  

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);  
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

2). on button cllick -  open Gallery for select image

```
Intent galleryintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
galleryintent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(galleryintent, IMAGE_PICK);
```

3). Static variables

```
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 0; 
    private static final int IMAGE_PICK = 1;
```

4). onActivityResult

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
        {
            switch(requestCode) 
            { 
                case CAMERA_REQUEST:
                    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                    {
                        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}; 
                        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null, null, null); 
                        int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); 
                        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
                        String capturedImageFilePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
                        Log.d("photos*******"," in camera take int  "+capturedImageFilePath);

                        Bitmap photo_camera = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(capturedImageFilePath, options);

                        if(data != null)
                        {
    img_1.setImageBitmap(photo_camera);
                                prefsEditor.putString(Global.PHOTO_1,capturedImageFilePath);
    }
    }
case IMAGE_PICK:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                {  
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

//                  Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                   Bitmap photo_gallery = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath,options);
                   img_1.setImageBitmap(photo_gallery);
                        prefsEditor.putString(Global.PHOTO_1, filePath);
}

}
        prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

5). in onDestroy()
  You have to destroy all bitmap which you setted.

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(photo_camera != null)
        {
            photo_camera.recycle();
        }
        if(photo_gallery != null)
        {
            photo_gallery.recycle();
        }
}
```

6). At the time when you fetch data from sharedPrefrences you have to convert string in to Bitmap and then you can set bitmap in ImageView.
for example, Bitmap bit1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(strimg1);
and then set , imageView.setImageBitmap

Comment: Thanks for the posting the solutions for your problem. Set your answer as selected to remove it from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 3):

Don't store bitmaps in a sharedpreference. If you need to persist it during the lifetime of your application, you can assign it to a `static` field. If you want to persist it even across device reboots, put it in a file or on the database.

For more information, read http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html#3

Answer (score 3):

Let's say the bitmap image as bitmapImg, you can **store the bitmap image after converting into a base64String like the below**

```
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmapImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

byte[] compressImage = baos.toByteArray();
String sEncodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(compressImage, Base64.DEFAULT);

mSharedPreferences.edit().putString("keyStoredImage",sEncodedImage);
mSharedPreferences.edit().commit();
```

**And retrieve the Stored Image from the SharedPreference like the below**

```
if(mSharedPreferences.contains("keyStoredImage"))
{

String encodedImage = mSharedPreferences.getString("keyStoredImage",null);

byte[] b = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);

Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add values in `SharedPreference` like this:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("abc", 0);
Editor edit = pref.edit();
edit.putBoolean(arg0, arg1);
edit.putFloat(arg0, arg1);
edit.putInt(arg0, arg1);
edit.putLong(arg0, arg1);
edit.putString(arg0, arg1);
edit.commit();
```

You can add only `Boolean, Float, Int, Long, String` values in `SharedPreference`.

To store image you should external or internal memory of device.

Comment: Thanks, I used as per you told. But now I want to Convert String to Bitmap from displaying my image. Can you have any idea for converting String to Bitmap?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405373/converting-string-as-a-bitmap-in-android